# Post render event in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I'm trying to add a click event listener to the label of all column-headers of a TableView, as follows:

```
for (final Node header : tblView.lookupAll(".column-header > .label")) {         
    if ((header != null) && (header instanceof Label)) {
        final Label headerLabel = (Label) header;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that if I do this in the initialize()-function of the Controller, the Scenegraph is not yet rendered and the above code won't work. Hence my question: Is there some kind of a post-render event?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `WINDOW_SHOWN` event in [javafx.stage.WindowEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/WindowEvent.html). That is not (imo) "Post render event" but you can utilize it in similar manner, by adding an event handler to the `Stage` (which extends from `Window`).

In the initialize method of controller class, get the primary stage and then:

```
stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent window) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                addListenerToColumnHeaders();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps, since didn't try myself.

Comment: This event handler works as expected, thanks! However, getting my hands on the primary stage within `initialize()` of the Main Controller is a problem on its own, as it seems... One solution is to grab the controller in the Main Class, but that couples the Application class and the Main Controller.

Comment: @Biy My application have number of Controllers and I need to make this while middle of some UI flow. When I add the WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN event handler as you mention, it will try to execute this event handler place which I have declared that mean with the execution of Application's start(Stage method), then I got some Null Pointer Exceptions. Can you please tell me how I can fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Channa, answered to your related question. Please have a look.